# Huge loading time on some pages

Tags: asp.net, performance, time, loading

Here is my page URL: www.1800-gifts.com/USA/Cake-Delivery and other pages like that all are loading very slow even i have caching , compression enabled, i have tried to call go daddy which is my hosting provider but they do not respond positive.

Developer is telling me that it is a server issue, but i don't find any issues in server it is fine.

This website is developed in asp.net 4.0, database is mssql 2012 r2.
server is VPS, with 2 gb of ram, I have 2 GB data in database, and some table contains more than 100k records.

Please look at my site and give me suggestions, i have checked in google page speed and other tools they are all saying different views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the cause but if you enable developer mode (F12) and run the site in chrome you will see that the cake-delivery page is the one that is causing the loading time (44s). You will also notice that there are JQuery errors on the page.

This could possibly be part of the problem.

EDIT:

After looking at the linked page I think Erik is right, JQuery is not the issue.

The person that is developing the site needs to revisit the way the page works completely. There is a massive amount of operations happening in the page load of the page. The operations that are used are also hack and slash ways of doing things that there is already built in methods for. This is simply a page taking forever to load due to bad coding.

I would suggest the developer returns to the drawing board.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate that, Please can you tell me that the jquery is the only thing that causing such issue? or is there something else too?

Comment: Without actually looking at the code it is difficult to say. I do however see 3 places where JQuery is used but it is pulling through as undefined. The first port of call would be to ensure that the reference links to the JQuery library is valid.

Comment: thanks again: i cannot post code here it is showing error so i uploaded here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-aJC2XFgzFnV1egxjhHw6DH_YeFoVaNI9fOEppD0aPY

Comment: jQuery really isn't the problem here. It's the server that takes ages to respond.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of great tools that look at your page and tell you what might be wrong with it. Analyzing your page with GTmetrix for example gives you [this](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.1800-gifts.com/AzyFIFfF). There are also important tips you can work on right away, for example:

1. gzip compression
2. Minifying css, html and js
3. Concatenating scripts

and a lot more. I also recently wrote an article showing important optimization for [web performance](https://medium.baqend.com/building-a-shop-with-sub-second-page-loads-lessons-learned-4bb1be3ed07#.gziys124f)

Looking at the waterfall chart of your page (also available on GTmetrix) shows that the biggest problem is indeed your server. It takes 16 seconds to receive an answer for the first request (time-to-first-byte). There is clearly something wrong!

There are a lot of things that could be wrong on your server. You should test your database queries (are they slow? How many are performed for a page load?).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Erik for the answer, On my page there are many database queries about 10 or more, but all are performing well when i run them.

Comment: If your server is hosted in a shared environment you might have issues with swapping to disk but the is just random guessing at this point. We would need more information on your backend for a better answer.

Comment: Can you please figure out what is wrong with the server? or give me any suggetion so i can prove godaddy that the problem is in server.

Comment: This website is developed in asp.net 4.0, database is mssql 2012 r2. server is VPS, with 2 gb of ram, I have 2 GB data in database, and some table contains more than 100k records. Server is in us

Comment: With the given information it's just not possible to say what exactly is wrong with the server but it's definitely something severe! You need to thoroughly debug what your server is doing while answering a request and identify where so much time is lost. If you want to start looking into web performance this might help: https://medium.baqend.com/building-a-shop-with-sub-second-page-loads-lessons-learned-4bb1be3ed07#.avaxh14nm. But first of all you need fix your backend processing.